# Does Unity 4.2 support x64 Windows Store applications?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I build my Windows Store application (created in Unity 4.2) in Visual Studio 2012 and choose x86 or ARM platform everything works fine, but when I try to build x64 the player folder (and DLL references) is missing.

Is it a problem with my installation or does Unity not support x64 Windows Store applications?

Please help me out . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only x86 and ARM are currently supported.